# Understanding issue with unit of work repository pattern, accessing within api

Tags: c#, unit-of-work, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to access my unit of work within my api project but I am having an issue with one of the function.

This is the main stock repo repository

```
public class StockRepository : GenericRepository<StockItem>, IStockRepository
{ 
    public StockRepository(WarehouseDBContext _context) : base(_context)
    { 
    }
    public IEnumerable<StockItem> GetAllStockItems()
    {
        return context.StockItems.ToList();
    }


    public  bool DoesStockItemExist(string? stockCode)
    {
      return  context.StockItems.Any(e => e.StockCode == stockCode);
    }
    public async Task<StockItem> FindStockItemByIdAsync(int? id)
    {
        return await context.StockItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id== id);

    }
    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    Task<List<StockItem>> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And this is the interface

```
public interface IStockRepository : IGenericRepository<StockItem>
{ 
    IEnumerable<StockItem> GetAllStockItems();
    Task<StockItem> FindStockItemByIdAsync(int? id);
    bool DoesStockItemExist(string? stockCode);
    Task<List<StockItem>> GetAll();
}
```

For some reason this will only hook up the reference if i do it like this.

```
     Task<List<StockItem>> IStockRepository.GetAll()
    {

        return context.StockItems.ToListAsync();
    }
```

If I do it like this it complains that the method is not implemented why is that?

```
 Task<List<StockItem>> GetAll()
 {

        return context.StockItems.ToListAsync();
 }
```

This is my generic interface.

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly WarehouseDBContext context;

    protected GenericRepository(WarehouseDBContext _context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get(int? id)
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task Add(T entity)
    {
        await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public bool Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Any(predicate);

    }

}
}
```

Edit 2

The second problem is that I cannot access the function here must I also have a reference to ISTock on my api controller

```
 public class StockItemsController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public StockItemsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.mapper = mapper;

    }

    public   Task<IEnumerable<StockItem>> GetAllStocItems()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.StockItems.Get();
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
}
```

Also for some reaosn its forcing me to cast it back to the object type

```
   public   Task<IEnumerable<StockItem>> GetAllStocItems()
    {
     return 
      (Task<IEnumerable<StockItem>>)_unitOfWork.StockItems.GetAllStockItems();
    }
```

**Edit 3**

This is my IunitOfWork Interface.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IFileAttachments FileAttachments { get; }
    ISalesOrder SalesOrders { get; }
    IShopppingCart ShoppignCarts { get; }
    IWarehouseApiClient WareHouseApi { get; }
    IStockRepository StockItems { get; }
    int Complete();

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have an `IStockRepository` to begin with. It breaks the GenericRepository pattern. Turn it into a service class that *has a* (instead of *is a*) `IGenericRepository<StockItem>`.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have in your `GenericRepository`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
{
    return await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

And then also in your interface you have

```
Task<List<StockItem>> GetAll();
```

So C# doesn't know to which interface your `GetAll()` is pointing too, that's why u need the explicit interface call.

What you should do is remove it from your `IStockRepository` since you already have it in your more generic one.

Comment: Why when I do that do i not get access to it in the unit of work object this is strange i will need to figure this out why

Comment: please see my edit quesiton 2 in the op i cant accesss the funciton on my api controller

Comment: You are not showing the interface IUnitOfWork, and you are having some weird implementation of the pattern, because you shouldnt be casting something back as a Task you would want the IEnumerable

Comment: The problem you are having is in your StockRepository you have the method GetAllStocItems return an IEnumerable<StockItem>, so the one from the Unit of Work you are calling is an IEnumerable<StockItem> there is something wrong with your pattern. What i can tell you is you shouldnt be using UnitOfWork With entity framework core, it does already implement it by default. In a transient Context, you can do all the operations you want and then call SaveChanges and that would be your unit of work